# unable to delete directory from SFTP server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to delete the directory from my SFTP server. I am using EnterpriseDT.Net.Ftp SSHSCPClient for connecting to the server with private key, no password.

When I use the

```
SSHSCPClient ftpConnection;

//Successfully connected and able to upload the files but

ftpConnection.MultipleDeleteDirectories(remoteFolder);
```

it throws the error

```
[Message = "This operation is not currently supported."]
```

Comment: What level of logging are you using?  Can you try adjusting the logging level ?  [link](https://enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/doc/manual/html/howtosetuplogging.html)

Comment: @jeffld I am not using any logging. I am seeing the above exception in my catch block

Comment: Can you delete the folder by logging onto the server using Putty or connecting using a different library like https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET ?

Comment: Yes I can able to delete the directory when I opened through WinSCP/FileZilla @Ignas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried `SSHSCPClient` from v9.1.3.20 assembly, and using [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) found out that `MultipleDeleteDirectories` and all other delete methods are throwing not supported exception deliberately. Screenshot below. Or by any chance they have another privately distributed assembly, which has all the methods implemented...

[image]

`edtFTPnetPRO` looks a little bit outdated. Unless you have a good reason to use this library, I would recommend using [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) which supports `.NET Core`, and is open source.